# Compare cell by cell in one column based on unique value in other column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Please help me to compare value cell by cell in one column based on the other column. Example:

```
Column A         Column B

January            No

January            Yes

February           Yes 

February           Yes

March              No

March              Yes
```

Based on this, I would like to highlight January and March due to its values in column B are not the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Use conditional formatting with a COUNTIFS formula.

Comment: @BigBen could you help to give more explanation? Thank you

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"<>"&B1)>0`.

Comment: Thank you. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably shorter way to accomplish this, but here's one method:

Create a column (Column C) an input this formula into cell C2 and drag it down.

```
    =IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),0,1)
```

Then highlight your data in column A, go to conditional formatting and use a formula such as this:

```
    =SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)>1
```

Results:

[image]